# Can Google Analytics API do: after looking at /faq.html, which pages did the users go to most often?

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api

using the Google Analytics Data Export API with

```
http://code.google.com/apis/analytics/docs/gdata/gdataExplorer.html
```

I put in`pagePath` and `nextPagePath` for dimensions, and `pageViews` for metrics, and filter for `ga:pagePath=~faq.html`

But it returned a table with pagePath equal to nextPagePath which is the faq.html path.  Is there a way to find the result?

Comment: This belongs on http://webapps.stackexchange.com/. To bad we can't move questions to beta-sites.

Comment: this can be a webapp but is also part of the data feed API... i think the data provided to Google is translated to a SQL statement as well, so it is quite programming related.

Comment: I agree with Jian - A lot of people are asking programming questions with regards to the Google Analytics API.

Answer (score 2):

I just found it:

http://code.google.com/apis/analytics/docs/gdata/gdataReferenceCommonCalculations.html#navigation

```
Which pages are users going to after test.html? 

dimensions=ga:nextPagePath
metrics=ga:pageviews 
filters=ga:previousPagePath=~test.html
```